# why am i getting Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'collection') in the code below?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

**i'm new to mongodb and dev web and i'm using mongodb with nodejs in this project and i got this problem "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'collection')" on postman when i send a request but in VS it connect to database without any problem could anyone help me please**
here is my code

that's my connection.js and here when i hover on collection and db it says in visual code it's undefined

```
const {MongoClient} = require('mongodb');
const {dbURL, dbName} = require('../config');



const client = new MongoClient(dbURL, {
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    useNewUrlParser:true
});

function Connect(){
    return new Promise(async(resolve, reject) =>{
        try {
            await client.connect();
            const db = client.**db**(dbName);
            const users = db.**collection**('users');
            users.createIndex({email: 1},{unique: 1});
            resolve(db, client);
        
           }catch(error){
            reject(error);
        
           }
    });
    
 };
module.exports = Connect;
```

i hope someone can find the solution here
and this is my index.js

```
const Connect = require('./connection');
const {port} = require('../config');
const app = require('./app');


Connect().then(({db}) => {
    app.setupRoutes(db);
    console.log('The database is connected');
}).catch((e) => {
    console.error("couldn't connect to database", e);

});

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`App listening on port ${port}!`));

module.exports = app;
```

and that's my app.js
as you see i'm using db.collection here

```
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");
const ValidationError = require('./errors/ValidationError');

const app = express();
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());

const handleNewUser = (user, db) => {
    return new Promise(async(resolve, reject)=>{
        try {
            const users = db.collection('users');
            const results = await users.insertOne(user);
            resolve(results.insertedId); 
        }catch (error){
            reject(error);
            
        }
    
    })
        
};

app.setupRoutes = (db) => {
    app.post('/users',async (req, res) =>{
        const user = req.body;
        
        try {
            const errors = validateUser(user);
            if(errors.length > 0) throw new ValidationError(errors, 'Validation Error');
            const results = await handleNewUser(user, db);
            res.status(201).send(results);
    
        }catch (error){
            if(error instanceof ValidationError)
            res.status(500).send({message:error.message,errors:error.errors});
            else if(error.message.startsWith('E11000 duplicate'))
                res.status(500).send('duplicate email.');
            else res.status(500).send(error.message);
        }
    
    });

}

module.exports = app;
```

i donét know what's wrong and i'm following a tutoriel

Comment: Where are tou getting the error?
Probably you need some await to wait the response somewhere.

Comment: i got it in postman when i send a post request it tells this "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'collection')"

Answer (score 0):

`resolve(db, client)` - you resolve not object but separate values "db" and "client".
`Connect().then(({db}) => {` -
tries to destructure the 'db' property of the first resolved value, and if your "db" value is not an object or doesn't have `.db` property, it would always be undefined.

So remove destructuring and use just the value:

```
Connect().then((db) => {
```

Comment: thank you so much it's just the semicolon that needs to be removed ...thank you Michael

Comment: Not the semicolon, but curly brackets around db, that force js engine to try to destructure object. Anyway - you're welcome! :)

Comment: Yes my mistake the curly brackets❤️